# PHP/MYSQL this select is giving 3 results repeated in a echo... why?

Tags: php, mysql, select

I am using this select and when I use while to output data, i have it repeated 3 times. Can some good soul help me? $idr is variable unique, dont have any repeated.

```
    $sqlRomaneio    =   'SELECT clientes.id_cliente,
                            clientes.razao_social, 
                            clientes.cpf_cnpj, 
                            clientes.identidade_inscricao, 
                            clientes.foto, 
                            clientes.tipo_cliente, 
                            romaneios.data_criacao, 
                            romaneios.id_endereco_entrega,
                            romaneios.modo_entrega, 
                            romaneios.custo_entrega_valor, 
                            romaneios.custo_entrega_pago_por, 
                            romaneios.modo_recebimento, 
                            romaneios.custo_recebimento_valor, 
                            romaneios.custo_recebimento_pago_por, 
                            romaneios.quantidade_pecas, 
                            romaneios.valor_total, 
                            romaneios.finalizado
                     FROM clientes, romaneios, clientes_enderecos 
                     WHERE romaneios.id_romaneio = '.$idr.'';
```

Comment: 1) what does your while loop look like?
2) what does this query return when you run it straight in MySQL?

Comment: Second the request for the rest of the code.  In your SQL query, you can add "LIMIT 1" to limit the results to the first matching record. ie. ... WHERE romaneios.id_romaneio = ' . $idr . ' LIMIT 1';

Comment: Isn't this the ideal circumstances for SQL injection (i.e., use prepared statements instead)?

Comment: @ladaghini it depends on where `$idr` is coming from, but yes, potentially. That's besides the point though as far as why there are three results returned from the query, instead of one.

Answer (score 1):

Two points:

**1**: You have the table `clientes_enderecos` listed but nothing is being selected from it and it does not appear in the where clause, so remove it.

**2**: You do not have a clause to restrict rows from `clientes` and `romaneios` by a matching foreign key.  So each row in `clientes` will appear once for every row in `romaneios`.

So you need to add another condition in your where clause.